# ¿Qué le estoy indicando a flexbox con esta opción flex: 1 0 auto?

Tags: css, css3

¿Qué significa el 1, el 0 y el auto? `flex: 1 0 auto;` al utilizar flexbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Qué significa el 1, el 0 y el auto? `flex: 1 0 auto;`

Los 3 valores son: flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis

**<'flex-grow'>**
Define el [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) del elemento flexible. Ver [`<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/number) para obtener más detalles . Los valores negativos no se consideran válidos . El valor predeterminado es 1 cuando se omite.

> La propiedad `flex-grow` de CSS especifica el factor de crecimiento de un elemento flexible. Se especifica qué cantidad de espacio debe ocupar el elemento dentro del contenedor flexible.

- En tu caso `1`, es decir, el tamaño es proporcional a 1.

**<'flex-shrink'>**
Define el [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) del elemento flexible. Ver [`<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/number) para obtener más detalles . Los valores negativos no se consideran válidos . El valor predeterminado es 1 cuando se omite.

> La propiedad `flex-shrink` de CSS especifica el factor de contracción de flexión de un elemento flexible.

- En tu caso `0`, es decir, se va a achicar 0 veces más rápido que sus hermanos.

**<'flex-basis'>**
Define el [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex-basis) del elemento flexible. Se acepta cualquier valor válido para las propiedades  width y height . Un tamaño preferente de 0 debe tener una unidad para evitar ser interpretado como flexible. El valor predeterminado es 0% cuando se omite.

> La propiedad `flex-basis`de CSS  específica la base flexible, la cual es el tamaño inicial de un elemento flexible. Ésta propiedad determina el tamaño de una caja de contenidos a no ser que se haya especificado de otra forma usando `box-sizing`.

- En tu caso `auto`, es decir, su tamaño inicial se calculara automáticamente.

Fuente: [flex - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Values)

Comment: +1. Con un ejemplo, la respuesta quedaría muy completa. Por ejemplo, mostrar en qué casos puede ser útil. Se me ocurren ejemplos como sticky header y footer, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Los valores comunes de flex:

**Flex: 0 auto;**

Esto es lo mismo que `flex: initial;`ya la taquigrafía para el valor por defecto: flex: 0 1 auto. Se da el tamaño del elemento basado en sus width/ height (o su contenido si no se establece).

**Flex: auto;**

Esto es equivalente a `flex: 1 1 auto`. Ten cuidado, este no es el valor por defecto. Se da el tamaño del elemento basado en sus width/ height, pero hace que sea totalmente flexible, de manera que absorbe cualquier espacio adicional a lo largo del eje principal.

**Flex: ninguno;**

Esto es equivalente a `flex: 0 0 auto`. Se da el tamaño del elemento de acuerdo con sus width/ height, pero lo hace totalmente inflexible.

**[Fuente](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)**

[css](/questions/tagged/css) [css3](/questions/tagged/css3)

Answer (score 3):

Según la documentación de **[w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-display-flex)** (sitio oficial), la propiedad `flex` permite a un contenedor distribuir el espacio libre a sus elementos (proporcional a su factor flex `grow`) para llenar el contenedor, o los encoge (proporcional al factor flex `shrink`) para evitar el desbordamiento (overflow).

Como puedes observar, la documentación te habla de dos propiedades de los elementos que están contenidos en un contenedor `flex` en su propia definición. Sin embargo, la propiedad `flex` puede adoptar los siguientes valores:

```
none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]
```

Y el valor inicial para la propiedad `flex` es:

```
flex: 1 0 auto
```

Cada uno de los posibles valores de la propiedad `flex` corresponde a:

- **`flex-grow`**: Este es el factor de crecimiento. Corresponde a un número que determina cuánto crecerá el elemento flexible en relación con el resto de los elementos flexibles dentro del contenedor `flex` si hay espacio libre. Cuando se omite es equivalente a poner un 1.
- **`flex-shrink`**: Este valor especifica el factor de encogimiento y es el que determina cuánto se contraerá el elemento flexible en relación con el resto de los elementos flexibles dentro del contenedor `flex` si falta espacio en el contenedor. Cuando se omite es equivalente a poner un 1.
- **`flex-basis`**: Este valor especifica el valor inicial de un elemento flexible antes de que el espacio libre se distribuya de acuerdo con los factores de flexión (`flex-grow` y `flex-shrink`). Cuando se omite su valor por defecto es 0.

Los valores que puede tomar `flex-basis` son:

- **`auto`**: Cuando toma este valor, `flex-basis` toma el valor de la propiedad principal de tamaño usada como `flex-basis`. Si este valor es `auto` por sí solo, entonces el valor usado es `content`.
- **`content`**: Indica ajuste automático de tamaño basado en el contenido del flex item.
- **`width`**: Para el resto de valores, `flex-basis` es resuelto de la misma manera que la anchura (width) y la altura (height).
- **`none`**: El valor none equivale a `0 0 auto`.

Por último, dejo una imagen sacada también de la documentación en la que diferencia entre establecer flex "absoluto" (empezando con un `flex-basis` de 0) o un flex "relativo" (partiendo del tamaño del contenido del elemento como base). Los tres elementos tienen factores flex de 1, 1 y 2 respectivamente. Fíjate que el elemento con un factor flex de 2 crece el doble.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]